# the name resources does not exist in the current context Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            EditText val1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtuser1);
            EditText val2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtuser2);
```

---

Error :

> The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same issue today in my `Xamarin` application. I tried the following things

1. Clean the solution and rebuild
2. Close Visual Studio and open again
3. Delete the `obj` and `bin` folder and rebuild the project

None of the above things worked for me. The real issue was because of that the file `Resource.Designer.cs` was excluded from my project and including that to the solution fixed the issue for me.

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Mine through a wobbly and a clean, rebuild and even PC restart wouldn't resolve it. In the end all I had to do was exlude Resource.Designer.cs from my project then include it again.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yea there are some bugs related to how `Resource.Designer.cs` is being handled it seems.

Answer (score 3):

I was so resolved (by visual studio)

1. Remove 3 line

   ```
   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
   EditText val1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtuser1);
   EditText val2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtuser2);
   ```
2. Build -> Clean
3. Build -> Rebuild
4. rewrite remove 3 line

Answer (score 3):

Following steps work for me

- Copy resource folder on desktop
- I successfully deleted the Resources folder from the project. I cleaned the solution then I closed the project and I restarted VS.
- I copied a copy of the same folder into the project tree and I included it again in the project.

Comment: All I needed to do of the above steps was to re-include the `Resources.designer.cs` file in my project. I'm keeping the file out of source control but the file itself still has to be referenced in the Android project in order for it to build.

Answer (score 1):

Each project has its own Resources, If you are using different namespaces then you can fix either three different ways:
Add

```
using myProjectName;
```

or change the namespace for

```
namespace myProjectName
```

or use qualified path:

```
myProjectName.resource
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had renamed the project and did a solution wide Find and Replace for the new name. But I found that when I unloaded the Android project and edited the `csproj` file, a reference to the old project name was still present in the `RootNamespace` and `AssemblyName` nodes