# Resource does not exist in the current context

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Following this [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/), after I created the project, there is already an error, and I haven't done anything yet:

> The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Phoneword
{
    [Activity(Label = "Phoneword", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main); <-- Error here
        }
    }
}
```

- Tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37517264/5597834), but didn't work.
- Checked this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5261/the-name-resource-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context), but as I said, I haven't done or add anything, so it does not work for me
- Tried Clean, Rebuild, Build, Restart but still the same
- Tried changing `Build Action` to `None`. Although the error disappeared, a new one appeared when debugging
- The weird thing is I can start debugging even if there is an error. Sometimes it is okay, but after a minute it will produce the red underline, but the word `Resource` has a color

What would be the way/setup to completely remove this error?

Comment: [Refer to this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/specify_default_namespace/), check the namespace, if you don't do anything, just create a project follow the tutorial, maybe there is something wrong in your compiler. Find `Resource.design.cs` to see if it exits in your project, the file created automatically when you create your project. If these doesn't work, please uninstall and install Visual Studio.

Comment: @JoeLv Already checked that, even with freshly created project, this error appears, and I haven't entered anything yet. `Resource.Designer.cs` also exists. I just installed this Visual Studio, so I don't think something will change if I uninstall install it, unless you can say specifically what part of the installation is the problem

Comment: If you don't want to uninstall and install, you can try to move the `Resource.Designer.cs` file to another locate and then clean, rebuild, now, it must be not work. And then copy `Resource.Designer.cs` file to your project, and rebuild.