# Xamarian - The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I'm aware this question has been asked already - but none provided a resolution.

I have read these links: 
[Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5261/the-name-resource-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context), [Stack Overflow Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517264/the-name-resources-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-xamarin) and some others.

I have a relatively simple project at the moment and I keep getting the error "The name 'Resource' does not exist in the current context"

I can restart the project & it will work and "resource" is underlined in red and I can still debug the project.

Then after a few tries it goes and complains that it's not in the current context.

I did not make any changes to the project - I have come back to it now from a while ago.

So I'm going to guess that updates to VS 2015 have broken it.

My Code example:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Graphics;

namespace Designer
{
    [Activity(Label = "Designer", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        // Global Varialble 
        Button butSignIn;
        EditText tbxUsername;
        TextView txtErrorMsg;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        butSignIn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.butSignIn);
        butSignIn.Click += ButSignIn_Click;

        tbxUsername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
        txtErrorMsg = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtErrorMessage);

        ActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.ParseColor("#ff70bc1e"));
        ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    }

    private void ButSignIn_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tbxUsername.Text == "Azmodan")
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MenuActivity));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish(); // this will close the activity and will close app if we try go back
        }
        else
        {
            txtErrorMsg.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            txtErrorMsg.Text = "inccorect login details, please try again";
        }   



    }



}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do i get you right, that your project builds, but you get red underlines indicating that something is wrong?

Comment: That's correct - but after few debugs it will says that the resource is not in the context.